# Copy a file of a server to another server from aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, windows, windows-server-2008

I need copy a file from server to another server using asp.net/VB.NET for example:

```
            'We copy the original file to the Temp dir
            If File.Exists(sFileSource) Then

                File.Copy(sFileSource, sFileDest, True)

            Else

                'The file doesn't exist

            End If
```

But when validate if file exists get that the file doesn't exist, I saw another forum that is a problem of network credentials because the paths are way //192.168.1.10/TemFile/file01.txt.

Comment: Can you give us some more info here?  What is the actual value of `sFileSource`, is the file on a network share, etc ...

Comment: sFileSource is \\192.168.1.25\TemFile\file01.txt, the directory is shared and has full permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the answer, using a system dll alow connect to oter servers by NetBios

```
<DllImport("advapi32.DLL", SetLastError:=True)> _
   Public Shared Function LogonUser(ByVal lpszUsername As String, ByVal lpszDomain As String, _
       ByVal lpszPassword As String, ByVal dwLogonType As Integer, ByVal dwLogonProvider As Integer, _
       ByRef phToken As IntPtr) As Integer
    End Function

Private _adminToken As IntPtr
Private _widCurrent As WindowsIdentity
Private _widAdmin As WindowsIdentity
Private _wic As WindowsImpersonationContext
Private _admin As AdminShared.AdminManager

If LogonUser(sUser, sDomain, sPassword, 9, 0, _adminToken) <> 0 Then

    _widAdmin = New WindowsIdentity(_adminToken)
    _wic = _widAdmin.Impersonate()

     File.Copy(sFileSource, sFileDest)

 Else
```